# Visual Studio C++ static lib function exposing problem

Tags: c++, visual-studio, static-libraries

I have created example of using static libraries. The goal is this functionality:

- DllTestFunctDll.dll links static_lib.lib (contains fnStaticLibrary())
- example.exe links DllTestFunctDll.dll (contains dllTestFunct())
- main() calls directly fnStaticLibrary() and dllTestFunct().
- dllTestFunct() calls directly fnStaticLibrary().

I don't understand one thing, **this works only if fnStaticLibrary() is inside same project as main() and dllTestFunct()**.

If I create another solution that

- DllTestFunctDll.dll links also static_lib.lib (contains fnStaticLibTest())
- main() newly also calls directly fnStaticLibTest().
- dllTestFunct() newly also calls directly fnStaticLibTest().

dllTestFunct() is able to call fnStaticLibTest() and main() is **unable** to call fnStaticLibTest() due to linker. But I am able to call fnStaticLibTest() inside dllTestFunct().

I used dumpbin to see what functions are exported:

```
dumpbin /EXPORTS "C:\\path\\DllTestFunctDll.dll"
```

Output:

```
ordinal hint RVA      name
      1    0 00001000 ?dllTestFunct@@YAXXZ = ?dllTestFunct@@YAXXZ (void __cdecl DllTestFunct(void))
      2    1 00001070 ?fnStaticLibrary@@YAXXZ = ?fnStaticLibrary@@YAXXZ (void __cdecl fnStaticLibrary(void))
```

**You can see that fnStaticLibTest() is missing inside the output.**

In both static lib projects I export function by "__declspec(dllexport) ".

I assume that the problem is inside the Visual Studio. Do you know how to solve it?

Thank you in advance for your answers.

**CODE (VS17 solution) LINK:** https://github.com/Ales5475/StaticLibProblemExample

Comment: When it doesn't work, what is the problem you have? What errors or runtime problems do you get? And do your main application link with `static_lib`? If not, why? A DLL is a totally separate entity, it's essentially a specially linked executable. The libraries a DLL links with are separate from the libraries that your application links with.

Comment: As I wrote, my main ampplication link static_lib, but not static_lib2. I unfortunatelly don't know why it is not linking. Maybe here we missunderstood, I will edit question.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion the point is that if .dll links .lib inside solution, .lib function is callable inside .exe. If .dll links .lib from another solution .lib function is callable inside .dll but not inside .exe.

Comment: And how is `static_lib2` involved? And Visual Studio is quite smart, if the library is in your solution, and you reference a function from it, VS probably links with the library for you. If you look at the references, linker settings, and the actual build output (which should show the commands and all arguments) what does it tell you?

Comment: Yeah this is probably the problem, that Visual Studio is doing something what I don't want. I set path to both static libraries in "General"->"Additional Library Directories" and also targets to "Input"->"Additional Dependencies". In "Command line" : /OUT:"C:\path\MainProgram\Release\DllTestFunctDll.dll" /MANIFEST /LTCG:incremental /NXCOMPAT /PDB:"C:\path\MainProgram\Release\DllTestFunctDll.pdb" /DYNAMICBASE "static_lib.lib" "static_lib2.lib" ...

Comment: Should be some specific switch inside build command? I don't know the VS build syntax much.

Comment: can't immediately find a stack overflow duplicate but see https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20140321-00/?p=1433

Comment: `main() is unable to call fnStaticLibTest() `  Please provide specific error message. Static libraries do not need __declspec(dllexport). And it will be better to upload your minimal reproducible example without personal privacy via Github.

Comment: LNK2001 unresolved external symbol "void __cdecl fnStaticLibTest(void)" (?fnStaticLibTest@@YAXXZ) MainProgram C:\path\MainProgram\MainProgram\MainProgram.obj 1

Comment: I have added code link to the problem. It is comprimed VS17 solution.

Comment: @Alan Birtles It seems that this should be the problem. But how to force VS to link the static library into the .obj or .lib?

Comment: This is a side-effect of the way the linker uses static libraries. It only includes function definitions to resolve undefined symbols in the DLL project. The declspec in the declaration is not enough. Since the DLL code does not itself call the function, it has no reason to include the definition and create the export. A simple workaround is to write a dummy call to the function in the DLL source code. Or use the linker's /EXPORT option. Or use #pragma comment(linker, "/export:?fnStaticLibTest@@YAXXZ") in the DLL source.

Comment: @Hans Passant You are probably right. But I call both libraries function in Dll. Also this "pragma comment" didn't work for both functions. LNK1120 1 unresolved externals 
 adn also LNK2001, do you know why? The name is exactly what you wrote me.

Comment: LNK1120 tells you that the #pragma worked.  But you didn't post the function declaration so I had to guess at the mangled name of the function.  Use dumpbin.exe /exports on the .lib file to see it.  Or declare the function `extern "C"` so the name doesn't get mangled beyond recognition.

Comment: @Hans Passant I cannot use the command, because build of .dll failed. Mangled names I solved by adding `extern "C"`.

Comment: May I know if your problem has been solved? I also noticed that mksteve updated his answer.

Comment: @Minxin Yu - MSFT I am still finding right answer. Only one which hardly workds is described by Hans Passant, adding the linker /EXPORT option.  There are also officital several ways https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/opt-optimizations?view=msvc-170 But a lot of people are complaining that it doesn't work...

Comment: What you're trying to do is the disadvantage of static library. It would be more convenient to design them all as dynamic libraries.

Comment: @Minxin Yu - MSFT I know that this should be possible. But is it possible to implement extern .dll functions inside main code (in .lib it is possible)? I agree that it is probably possible to avoid this problem using another approach (.dll). I selected this approach to avoid a lot of .dll files attached with my program...

Comment: The talk in reply  is beyond the scope of this question. You can use dumpbin to view the functions exported by the dynamic library. But the static library cannot view the export, just use it directly.

Answer (score 1):

An object module is added from a .lib, if it is required.  If the dll does not call (or reference) any item in a compilation unit (c/cpp file), it won't be added to the dll

This behavior is important for libraries, as it ensures that when linking against the C/C++ runtimes, then you don't import the whole of the libraries.  Just those which are required.

In your case you have a DLL which doesn't require the test function, and a .EXE which expects the DLL to have it.  There is no visible requirement for the test function when the DLL is being built.

Comment: Are you sure, that is true? If I add static library, it should be similar to copy code (.h and .cpp) to the .dll. And if there is `__declspec(dllexport)` before function inside static .lib header, I would expect that this function should be visible. However, why is one static function (inside solution) added and second (outside solution) is not?

Comment: I would like to react to your edit. The both static library functions are also called in function in DLL. Please see the code which I posted in a link.

Answer (score 0):

A DLL has explicit exports.  Either

```
__declspec(dllexport)
```

or a .DEF file with exports.  In this case, it appears that the static lib doesn't know if it is in a DLL or the EXE, so isn't decorated with `declspec(dllexport)` the best solution is for the .def file for the DLL to explicitly export the function.

The code in StaticLibTest.h

```
__declspec(dllexport) void fnStaticLibTest();
```

is inconsistent with the code in StaticLibTest.cpp

```
void fnStaticLibTest(){
```

This will not cause the function to be exported.  In general include a file which declares a function / structure to ensure it is consistent.

The correct form is

```
void __declspec(dllexport) fnStaticLibTest(){
```

and

```
void __declspec(dllexport) fnStaticLibTest();
```

Otherwise you are adding the attribute to the `void`.

Comment: All static libraries functions have `declspec(dllexport)` before function declaration, as I wrote at problem description bellow. So, from static library definition I would assume that the static library code is just added to .dll and due to this reason it should be accessible from .exe.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the snippet  I did use  `#pragma comment` successfully.

DLL:

```
__declspec(dllexport)   void DllTestFunct();

...
  #pragma comment(linker, "/export:fnStaticLibTest")
  void DllTestFunct() {
    fnStaticLibrary();
    fnStaticLibTest();
    printf("Hello world (Dynamic library)!\n");
    }
```

DLL's dependency:
Header Folder:

```
XXX\StaticLibTest\StaticLibTest;
XXX\MainProgram\StaticLibrary;
```

DLL Folder:

```
XXX\StaticLibTest\x64\Debug;
XXX\MainProgram\x64\Debug;
```

DLL  input:

```
StaticLibTest.lib;
StaticLibrary.lib
```

Static Lib:

```
  extern "C" void fnStaticLibTest();
...
extern "C" void fnStaticLibTest() {
    printf("Hello World! (Static library from another project)\n");
}
```

Comment: Can you share code with me, please. `#pragma comment(linker, "/export:fnStaticLibTest")` always throw linker errors for me (LNK1120 and LNK2001).

Comment: I'm not allowed to upload project. This is all code you need to modify in DLL and StaticLibTest. I am using VS2022(but should have little effect). Try to copy and paste carefully. Also don't forget to input StaticLibTest.lib and
StaticLibrary.lib in DLL properties.

Comment: If these lines are everything what you changed. It doesn't work for me. I have ".h" in C++ dependencies. "*.lib" in Linker Input and path to .lib in linker paths. Also I have question, why is `extern "C"` put after  `__declspec(dllexport)`? And also, why is `__declspec(dllexport)` missing in Static Lib? I think that this should'nt have to work.

Comment: Static libraries do not need __declspec(dllexport), which is used in dynamic libraries.

Comment: Still same problem, I don't know why, but everytimes I add this `#pragma comment(linker, "/export:fnStaticLibTest")`, linker throws error. How did you test that it was working?

Comment: I did not encounter Lnk2001. Only lnk2019, which is caused by incorrect input .
Check which function the error message is about. It will be better to rebuild using the link you provided.

Comment: Different linker errors may be caused by different versions of Visual Studio. But how did you tested that symbol from library in different solution is visible in .exe? Did you call it directly in .exe?